# How to access variable from while loop in python, import it to another .py file and print it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two Python files, I want to access variable from while loop `while True`.

Print it to another python file

**main.py**

```
#main.py

import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import subprocess
import os
import sys


def restart_program():
    python = sys.executable
    print(python)
    os.execl(python, python, *sys.argv)


def speak(text):
  engine = pyttsx3.init()
  engine.say(text)
  engine.runAndWait()


def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
          print("cancle")
          print("Exception: " + str(e))
          # return Task()

    return said.lower()


def Task():
  r = sr.Recognizer()
  with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
    said = ""
    try:
        # audio = r.listen(source, timeout=3)
        print("listening...")
        said = r.recognize_google(audio)
        said = said.lower()
        # said = "alexa play a song"
        # said = "alexa navigate me"
        if 'alexa' in said:
          command = said.replace("alexa", "")
          print(command)
        else:
          command = "null"
    except:
      command = "null"
  return command


def process_command(command):
  print(command)
  if ('cancel' in command or 'nevermind' in command or 'forget it' in command):
    speak("Sorry.")

  SONG_STRS = ["play a song", "sing"]
  for phrase in SONG_STRS:
    if phrase in command:
      speak("What would you like to play?")
      song = get_audio()
      if ('cancel' in song or 'nevermind' in song or 'forget it' in song):
        speak("Sorry.")
      else:
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
        speak("I've done that.")


  NAV_STRS = ["navigate me to", "start navigate", "let's go to"]
  for phrase in NAV_STRS:
    if phrase in command:
      speak("Where would you like Go?")
      place = get_audio()
      if ('cancel' in song or 'nevermind' in song or 'forget it' in song):
        speak("Sorry.")
      else:
        speak("okay, let's go to." + place)

  if 'restart' in command or 'reload' in command:
    speak("Cake and grief counseling will be available at the conclusion of the test.")
    restart_program()

print(place) #and also print here

while True:
  command = Task()
  process_command(command)
```

And also print place in `main.py`.

`value.py`:

```
#value.py

x = place  #this is variable from main.py --> def process_command

print(x)
```

Comment: `place` is local variable in the `process_command` function, not part of the module.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't just access the variable directly. You can pass its value as an argument to other functions or return its value from the function where you declare it. I suggest you read more about functions, return values, and arguments to understand this better.

Comment: Also you need to learn about "variable scope".